# How to install "gatsby-plugin-sharp" plugin

Tags: gatsby

When I run the command `gatsby develop` to start development server, I get the following error message:

> success open and validate gatsby-configs — 0.006 s error UNHANDLED
>   REJECTION
>
> Error: Unable to find plugin "gatsby-plugin-sharp". Perhaps you need
>   to install its package?
>
> - load.js:107 resolvePlugin
>     [gatsby-site]/[gatsby]/dist/bootstrap/load-plugins/load.js:107:11
> - load.js:119 processPlugin
>     [gatsby-site]/[gatsby]/dist/bootstrap/load-plugins/load.js:119:20
> - load.js:169 config.plugins.forEach.plugin
>     [gatsby-site]/[gatsby]/dist/bootstrap/load-plugins/load.js:169:20
> - Array.forEach
> - load.js:168 module.exports
>     [gatsby-site]/[gatsby]/dist/bootstrap/load-plugins/load.js:168:20
> - index.js:56
>     [gatsby-site]/[gatsby]/dist/bootstrap/load-plugins/index.js:56:21
> - Generator.next
> - new Promise
> - index.js:96
>     [gatsby-site]/[gatsby]/dist/bootstrap/load-plugins/index.js:96:17
> - index.js:128
>     [gatsby-site]/[gatsby]/dist/bootstrap/index.js:128:36
> - Generator.next

And when I try to install it, it shows following message:

```
 npm install --save gatsby-plugin-sharp
```

> > sharp@0.21.3 install D:\gatsby-site\node_modules\sharp
> >     (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
>
> info sharp Downloading
>   https://github.com/lovell/sharp-libvips/releases/download/v8.7.0/libvips-8.7.0-win32-x64.tar.gz
>   D:\gatsby-site\node_modules\sharp\install\libvips.js:78
>             throw err;
>
> D:\gatsby-site\node_modules\sharp>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp
>   (node "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\....\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
>   rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
>   rebuild ) gyp ERR! configure error gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find
>   Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable. gyp
>   ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)
>   gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder. (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)
>   gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
>   gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21) gyp ERR!
>   System Windows_NT 6.1.7601 gyp ERR! command "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
>   "rebuild" gyp ERR! cwd D:\gatsby-site\node_modules\sharp gyp ERR! node
>   -v v8.11.1 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2 gyp ERR! not ok npm WARN eslint-plugin-graphql@2.1.1 requires a peer of graphql@^0.12.0 ||
>   ^0.13.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies
>   yourself. npm WARN express-graphql@0.6.12 requires a peer of
>   graphql@^0.10.0 || ^0.11.0 || ^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0 but none is
>   installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN
>   graphql-tools@3.1.1 requires a peer of graphql@^0.13.0 but none is
>   installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN
>   ts-pnp@1.0.1 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed.
>   You must install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN optional
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules\fsevents):
>   npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for
>   fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
>   {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! sharp@0.21.3
>   install: `(node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy &&
>   prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)` npm
>   ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the sharp@0.21.3
>   install script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm.
>   There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\sharmatarun1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-04-02T06_36_07_771Z-debug.log

I have already searched for this error from git site but the issue came out the same. Please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Did you `npm install` all the dependencies for your project?
If you don't use `gatsby-plugin-sharp`, you could remove it from the gatsby-config.js and see if your app is running without it.

Something seems to be wrong with your Python environment: 
`Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.`
Do you get this error when `npm install`ing other packages?

Comment: Yes jacob when i remove gatsby-plugin-sharp  from the gatsby-config.js the app run but showing me blank web page. But i want to display images on web page which is not running and the PYTHON env variable issue i did't get during npm installing. How can i run my project plz help.

Comment: Can you share your repository? Just based off the error message above it's not possible to really see what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install C++ tools : 
Visual Studio Community 2015 or 2017 Package
and npm config set msvs_version 2015

> npm install --global --production windows-build-tools

The tool does not seem compatible with python 3
You can force the use of Python 2 after installing it
npm config set python python2.7
or

> node-gyp install --python C:\Python27